# Find the value of a definite integral given another definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm given a multiple choice question stating:

It is known that $\int _0^4\:f\left(x\right)dx=6$. The value of $\int _3^7\:f\left(x-3\right)+2dx$ is:

A) 8

B) 10

C) 14

D) 16

E) 18

Sorry if it is a really easy question, I'm currently doing Year 11 Calculus so this is my first year doing it. I've been trying this all day but can't figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you! Will keep that in mind for the next post

Comment: In addition to the below answers, i would like to add  - $\int_{3}^{7} f(x-3) dx $ ??, we look how $(x-3)$ varies? we  have $3 \leq x \leq 7$, from which we have $0 \leq (x-3) \leq 4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ goes from 3 to 7, $x-3$ goes from 0 to 4. Thus
$$\int_3^7(f(x-3)+2)\,dx=\int_0^4(f(x)+2)\,dx$$
Now we can split the integral:
$$=\int_0^4f(x)\,dx+\int_0^42\,dx$$
The left one is given to be 6 and the right one is easily evaluated:
$$=6+2\cdot(4-0)=14$$

Answer (score 1):

If we use linearity of the integral we see that

$$\int_{3}^{7}h(x)+g(x)dx = \int_{3}^{7}h(x)dx+\int_{3}^{7}g(x)dx$$

In your case this means that

$$\int_{3}^{7}f(x-3)+2dx = \int_{3}^{7}f(x-3)dx+\int_{3}^{7}2dx$$

Do you know how we can do variable substitution to relate the integral

$$\int_{3}^{7}f(x-3)dx$$

to

$$\int_{0}^{4}f(x)dx$$